# C# speedup method call of a generic class using expressions

Tags: c#, .net, generics, lambda

I need to call an instance method of a generic class. The signature looks like this:

```
public class HandlerFactory
{
    public static IHandler<T> Create<T>();
}

public interface IHandler<T>
{
    T Read(Stream s);

    void Write(Stream s, T v);
}
```

I managed to get it working by using expressions and DynamicInvoke. Sadly the performance of DynamicInvoke isn't that great. I can't cast the delegate to an `Action<MemoryStream, T>` because I don't know the type at compile time.

```
public class Test
{
    public static void Write(MemoryStream s, object value)
    {
        var del = GetWriteDelegateForType(value.GetType());

        // TODO: How to make this faster?
        del.DynamicInvoke(s, value);
    }

    private static object GetHandlerForType(Type type)
    {
        var expr = Expression.Call(typeof(HandlerFactory), "Create", new[] { type });
        var createInstanceLambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<object>>(expr).Compile();
        return createInstanceLambda();
    }

    private static Delegate GetWriteDelegateForType(Type type)
    {
        var handlerObj = GetHandlerForType(type);
        var methodInfo = handlerObj.GetType().GetMethod("Write", new[] { typeof(MemoryStream), type });

        var arg1 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(MemoryStream), "s");
        var arg2 = Expression.Parameter(type, "v");

        var handlerObjConstant = Expression.Constant(handlerObj);
        var methodCall = Expression.Call(handlerObjConstant, methodInfo, arg1, arg2);

        var lambda = Expression.Lambda(methodCall, arg1, arg2);

        return lambda.Compile();
    }
}
```

Please note, I didn't benchmark the lambda generation, just the call to DynamicInvoke.

Is there any way to replace DynamicInvoke with something faster?

**Update:** I evaluated the 3 answers which contained code samples and choose to go with Lasse V. Karlsen answer because of the simplicity.
*(Note on Grax's code: despite caching the MakeGenericMethod call it seems to be way slower than wrapping Invoke in a delegate)*

```
             Method |        Median |     StdDev |
------------------- |-------------- |----------- |
           MyLambda | 1,133.2459 ns | 25.1972 ns |
       ExplicitCall |     0.6450 ns |  0.0256 ns |
 Test2DelegateLasse |    10.6032 ns |  0.2141 ns |
         LambdaGroo |    10.7274 ns |  0.1099 ns |
         InvokeGrax |   349.9428 ns | 14.6841 ns |
```

Comment: Can you create a [mcve] that people could tinker with? One that times a specific set of existing code, so that I could run it on my computer to get a baseline, then tinker with it to see if I could get a faster way of doing it?

Comment: Having a generic interface for a plugin factory doesn't really make sense, IMHO.

Comment: It's a third party library, so I can't decide if it makes sense. Here is a full working example demonstrating the performance: http://pastebin.com/K3q4dgMk . It's 820ms to 2ms on my PC comparing direct method call with DynamicInvoke.

Comment: I don't see how wrapping Invoke in a delegate is helping you.  The delegate is type-specific.  If you already know the type, just call the explicit handler directly.  Otherwise you still need a mechanism to get from the object type to the explicit type call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way to do this is to go through a proper generic method, wrapping up a cast from `object` to the `T`, and skipping the entire dynamic invoke.

From your code in the pastebin, here's a new version of your Test class:

```
public class Test2
{
    private static readonly Action<MemoryStream, object> del;

    static Test2()
    {
        var genericCreateMethod = typeof(Test2).GetMethod("CreateWriteDelegate", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        var specificCreateMethod = genericCreateMethod.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(Model));
        del = (Action<MemoryStream, object>)specificCreateMethod.Invoke(null, null);
    }

    public static void Write(MemoryStream s, object value)
    {
        del(s, value);
    }

    private static Action<MemoryStream, object> CreateWriteDelegate<T>()
    {
        var handler = HandlerFactory.Create<T>();
        return delegate (MemoryStream s, object value)
        {
            handler.Write(s, (T)value);
        };
    }
}
```

On my machine your code, with the above as well executes as:

> Your test: 1285ms
>   My test: 20ms
>   Explicit: 4ms

Comment: Your solution is the simplest one and it even runs ~5% faster than my solution on my machine. But you might want to move the initialization from the static constructor into the `Write` method, because right now you have hardcoded `<MemoryStream, Model>` generic parameters. Also, the delegate syntax is so 2006. :)

Comment: The delegate syntax may be old but I tend to err on the side of caution when posting code here, to avoid people dismissing the code for the wrong reasons :) The code is in no way production-ready, it should be wrapped in a class that per-type caches the created delegates and creates them on-demand. I simply mirrored the pastebin code of the OP to make it easier to compare.

Comment: My point is, you replaced `value.GetType()` for `typeof(Model)`, which (at least for me) made it slightly harder to compare it. There is no `Model` in OP's code, as far as I can see.

Comment: Thanks for the excellent and simple answer. I updated my post with proper benchmark results.

Answer (score 3):

Write a generic method and use MakeGenericMethod with Invoke to call it.

Store the method you want to call in a static variable so the GetMethod call only needs to happen once.

Then call MakeGenericMethod on that MethodInfo and Invoke on the result.

```
private static MethodInfo GenericWriteMethod =
    typeof(Test).GetMethod("GenericWrite", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);

public static void Write(MemoryStream s, object value)
{
    GenericWriteMethod
        .MakeGenericMethod(value.GetType())
        .Invoke(null, new object[] { s, value });
}

private static void GenericWrite<T>(MemoryStream s, T value)
{
    HandlerFactory.Create<T>().Write(s, value);
}
```

In my testing, this made it over 100 times faster.

Comment: That solution could also be improved to avoid `MakeingGenericMethod`. Combining this with some expressions to have the resulting `Action` would be fastest solution possible.

Comment: I tested by rewriting the code he pasted on pastebin to do the same thing you've posted here and I'm down to about 5x time used for the explicit write. This is definitely the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

You should simply create an `Action<Stream, object>` instead:

```
static Action<Stream, object> GetWriteDelegateForType(Type type)
{
    // get the actual generic method
    var handlerObj = GetHandlerForType(type);
    var methodInfo = handlerObj
                .GetType()
                .GetMethod("Write", new[] { typeof(MemoryStream), type });

    // but use (Stream, object) parameters instead
    var streamArg = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Stream), "s");
    var objectArg = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object), "v");

    // this will cast object to T
    var tCast = Expression.Convert(objectArg, type);

    var handlerObjConstant = Expression.Constant(handlerObj);
    var body = Expression.Call(handlerObjConstant, methodInfo, streamArg, tCast);
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Action<Stream, object>>(body, streamArg, objectArg);

    // and compile to an actual Action<Stream, object>
    return lambda.Compile();
}
```

And then you just call it like a plain delegate:

```
static void Write(MemoryStream s, object value)
{
    var action = GetWriteDelegateForType(value.GetType());
    action(s, value);
}
```

It would be also good idea to cache the delegate:

```
static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<Type, Action<Stream, object>> _cache = 
   new ConcurrentDictionary<Type, Action<Stream, object>>();

static void Write(MemoryStream s, object value)
{
    var type = value.GetType();
    var action = _cache.GetOrAdd(type, GetWriteDelegateForType);
    action(s, value);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for speeding up my expression code. But I'll stick with Lasse V. Karlsen answer because I think it's easier to understand than expressions. Nevertheless your code is fast!

Answer (score 0):

You could just make it an `Action<MemoryStream, object>` and simply use `Expression.Convert()` to change type of `v` from `object` to `type`.

For performance gain, you could just store those `Action`s in some `Type`-keyed dictionary (concurrent?), but the expressions would require some changes to `Create` the the handlers inside of them.

Comment: I already cache the expressions, the problem is just the call to DynamicInvoke which is slow. I can't change the code for HandlerFactory or IHandler because it's a third party library.

Comment: My solution does not involve any changes to the library. You just need to change `GetWriteDelegateForType` so it accepts parameter `v` of type `object` and then performs the conversion on it. Such expression tree can then be compiled to non-generic `Action` and invoked without any performance loss. Then, `Action` can be cached and its performance should be similar to one of the regular method. I can add pseud-code for the resulting `Action` if that is any help, you could try to convert it to expression tree later on.

Answer (score 0):

Adding another answer because this one is significantly different than my first one.

TLDR: Add a non-generic interface, create a dictionary to cache the handler for a type, call the handler using a non-generic Write method.

---

Add a non-generic interface to ExplicitHandler to make it easier to interact with in non-generic code.

```
public interface IHandler
{
    void Write(Stream s, object v);
}
```

Implement the non-generic Write method in ExplicitHandler to cast to T and call the generic Write

```
    void IHandler.Write(Stream s, object v)
    {
        Write(s, (T)v);
    }
```

Cache the handlers in a dictionary

```
public class Test
{
    static Dictionary<Type, IHandler> delegates = new Dictionary<Type, IHandler>();

    public static void Write(MemoryStream s, object value)
    {
        IHandler handler;

        var type = value.GetType();
        if (!delegates.TryGetValue(type, out handler))
        {
            handler = (IHandler)typeof(HandlerFactory).GetMethod(nameof(HandlerFactory.Create)).MakeGenericMethod(type).Invoke(null, null);
            delegates[type] = handler;
        }

        handler.Write(s, value);
    }
}
```

Rewrite of your source here: http://pastebin.com/hmfj2Gv2

Comment: Thanks for your response, but as stated in the comments I can't modify the IHandler interface, since it comes from a thirdparty library.

Comment: The non-generic IHandler is a completely different interface than the generic IHandler interface.  You could even call it something else.  The real question is can you modify the explicit handler to also implement your non-generic write method.  If not, you can always write a wrapper class that contains the non-generic Write method and a reference to the generic handler.